# jQuery function not completing / Avia Slider

Tags: jquery, function

I'm using the Avia slider to create an image rotator, however I've modified the code slightly in order to change between images when you hover over the slider using code like so:

```
if(options.autorotation == false ) 
                {   
                $('.mask').mouseenter( function() {
                    currentSlideNumber ++;
                    if(currentSlideNumber == slideCount) currentSlideNumber = 0;    
                    slideWrapper.methods.switchSlide();         
});             
                $('.mask').mouseleave( function() {
                    currentSlideNumber ++;
                    if(currentSlideNumber == slideCount) currentSlideNumber = 0;    
                    slideWrapper.methods.switchSlide();

});

}
```

It works correctly, but I've noticed that it breaks if you mouseout before the transition has finished. How could I implement this so that if the user mouses our or in while the transition is in progress it won't break the slider.

Here's a link to a zip file of my full code: http://www.wearegrove.co.uk/fader.zip

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the above code with

```
$('.mask').mouseenter( function() {
        if(!skipSwitch)
        {
            currentSlideNumber ++;
            if(currentSlideNumber == slideCount)   
            currentSlideNumber = 0; 
            slideWrapper.methods.switchSlide();
        }

                  });
$('.mask').mouseleave( function() {
        if(!skipSwitch)
        {
            currentSlideNumber ++;
            if(currentSlideNumber == slideCount) currentSlideNumber = 0;    
            slideWrapper.methods.switchSlide();
        }

                   });

}
```

Hopefully that'll work.

Let me know if you want an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for that. While it has improved the functionality somewhat - if the user mouses out while the animation is being carried out, it still doesn't revert back once the animation has completed. If the user has moused out during the animation, it should repeat - also if they mouse in while the animation on the mouse out is executing. That's the effect I'm trying to achieve. Thanks, Chris.